# Why does chrome crash when checking or deleting cookies?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, crash

Whenever I try to it just crashes, and I haven't been able to find anyone else with this exact problem. I am only trying to delete one cookie at a time. I have run a scan with malwarebytes and removed some viruses but that didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting my computer seems to have fixed the problem for now.